# route back to last page(module) instead of last status

Tags: angularjs, typescript, routes, angular2-routing, aurelia

In Typescript is there any way to get the last module instead of last status, As an example 
if some one routes
from  page A to page B ,
inside page B 
from some proceeding he adds some optional parameters.
when the back button clicks user has to be able to go back to page A directly without going to the route that Page B without optional parameters

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code worked for me to get the module of the last page visited. Pls try.

```
import { Router , NavigationEnd} from '@angular/router';

  export class myComponent {
    private previousUrl: string;

    constructor(private router: Router){

      router.events
         .filter(event => event instanceof NavigationEnd)
         .subscribe(e => {
            let path = this.previousUrl;
            if(path !="" && path!=undefined){
               let res = path.split("/");
               console.log(res[1]); /* here in res[1] you will get the last clicked page module url. Now you can route to last module using this res[1] value */
            }
         this.previousUrl = e.url;

      });
   }
 }
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: this is actually what the answer should be